Is there anyone alive, who are descent of a God (maybe Rama, Krishna, etc) in Hinduism like great grandkids
Is there anyone alive, who is descent of a God (maybe Rama, Krishna, etc) in Hinduism like great grandkids

Kashyapa is the father of Devas. Present day there are people whose gotra is Kashyapa (kASyapasa gotra). Such people would perhaps be related to Devas.

I mean there seem to be Raghumshis and Yadavs still

https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/we-are-lord-ram-s-descendants-say-mewar-royals-third-claim-in-a-week/story-raJ7KUw0ENWxwcD52FsgfP.html

https://www.newindianexpress.com/nation/2019/Aug/25/meet-the-eight-individuals-who-claim-to-be-lord-rams-descendant-2024349.html

Paraśurāma and Vyāsa are both avatāras of Viṣṇu, and both are still alive, if that's what you are interested in knowing. Grandkids and great grandkids of Kṛṣṇa and Rāma, are already dead, surely in the case of Rāma and most likely in the case of Kṛṣṇa.
